# Using Requests and lxml, get href values for rows in a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

Python 3

I am having a hard time iterating through the rows of a table.

How do I iterate the `tr[1]` component through the number of rows in the table body for teamName, teamState, teamLink xpaths?

```
import lxml.html
from lxml.etree import XPath
url = "http://www.maxpreps.com/rankings/basketball-winter-15-16/7/national.htm"

rows_xpath = XPath('//*[@id="rankings"]/tbody)
teamName_xpath = XPath('//*[@id="rankings"]/tbody/tr[1]/th/a/text()')
teamState_xpath = XPath('//*[@id="rankings"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()')
teamLink_xpath = XPath('//*[@id="rankings"]/tbody/tr[1]/th/a/@href')

html = lxml.html.parse(url)

for row in rows_xpath(html):
    teamName = teamName_xpath(row)
    teamState = teamState_xpath(row)
    teamLink = teamLink_xpath(row)
    print (teamName, teamLink)
```

I have also attempted this through the following:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

siteItem = ['http://www.maxpreps.com/rankings/basketball-winter-15-16/7/national.htm'
            ]

def linkScrape():
    page = requests.get(target)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#Get team link
    for link in tree.xpath('//*[@id="rankings"]/tbody/tr[1]/th/a/@href'):
        print (link)
#Get team name        
    for name in tree.xpath('//*[@id="rankings"]/tbody/tr[1]/th/a/text()'):
        print (name)
#Get team state        
    for state in tree.xpath('//*[@id="rankings"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()'):
        print (state)

for target in siteItem:
    linkScrape()
```

Thank you for looking :D

Comment: Not really able how to help you, just dropping a hint that if you need to parse XML/HTML, BeatfiulSoup may be better option for you than pure lxml. If you're not forced to use lxml, check that library out.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.  Can you elaborate on how the code in your examples does not meet your needs?  In particular, I'm not sure what you mean by "iterate the tr[1] component"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to iterate over the rows in the `ranking` table.  So, start with a loop over those rows:

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.parse('http://www.maxpreps.com/rankings/basketball-winter-15-16/7/national.htm')

for row in doc.xpath('//table[@id="rankings"]/tbody/tr'):
```

This will iterate over each row in that document.  Now, for each row, extract the data you want:

```
    team_link = row.xpath('th/a/@href')[0]
    team_name = row.xpath('th/a/text()')[0]
    team_state = row.xpath('td[contains(@class, "state")]/text()')[0]
    print(team_state, team_name, team_link)
```

Which on my system yields output along the lines of:

```
CA Manteca /high-schools/manteca-buffaloes-(manteca,ca)/basketball-winter-15-16/rankings.htm
MD Mount St. Joseph (Baltimore) /high-schools/mount-st-joseph-gaels-(baltimore,md)/basketball-winter-15-16/rankings.htm
TX Brandeis (San Antonio) /high-schools/brandeis-broncos-(san-antonio,tx)/basketball-winter-15-16/rankings.htm
```